# Emacs doesn't seem to recognize .emacs.d on the latest Windows Insider Preview

Tags: init-file, spacemacs, microsoft-windows

I was able to use Emacs normally on Windows until the latest update to `Build 17711.rs_prerelease.180703-1539`. Now, whenever I start Emacs, it just shows the default welcome page, even though `.emacs.d` is still present in my home folder with all the `spacemacs` configurations in it. It seems that it's just ignoring `.emacs.d` altogether. I wonder if this has something to do with some changes introduced in this update.

If I change `.spacemacs` to `.emacs`, Emacs does seem to pick it up and apply some settings (e.g. the `variable-pitch` font specification). However, it apparently still can't use `.emacs.d` properly and still shows the default welcome page.

Maybe it has something to do with the folder name which contains two dots. Is there a way to configure Emacs to look for a folder with a different name to `.emacs.d`?

- Emacs: `25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)` from Emacs-w64 project
- System: Windows 10 Pro Insider Preview `Build 17711.rs_prerelease.180703-1539`

Comment: When this happens to me, usually it is due to there being a .emacs file present (maybe a default file was copied over?). When this file is present then the contents of .emacs.d are ignored. So I would first check for that.

Comment: @InHarmsWay Thanks for the advice though it happened just after the update with everything else remaining the same. Running as Administrator fixed the issue though I'm not sure why. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Somebody on Github](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11008#issuecomment-403325443) pointed out that the current workaround for the issue is to use "Run as Administrator" on `runemacs.exe`.